# How to enter text in cmd prompt using batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to open the command prompt through batch file and enter the text in the command prompt. I used the following method but it does not work.

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
CALL "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
cd C:\Programms\ramkumar\Java\HelloWorld
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

But it still remains in C:\Programms\ramkumar\Java\HelloWorld and not executing the java program.

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: Is `java -version` showing anything on cmd?

Comment: @Dale- No. Its not showing anything about version

Comment: @hellboy- Its not compiling the java program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your batch script doesn't work the way you want it to because:

In the batch script, there is a **CALL** to execute cmd.exe , which essentially opens a new **cmd** instance on top of the current **cmd** instance and pauses the execution of the main script. So unless you exit the new instance created by cmd.exe, the batch file won't proceed further.

**One possible solution:**

Copy the last 3 lines of your batch script into a new batch file and call this new batch file from your current batch file using **START** or **CALL**.

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
CALL cmd /K "path_to_new_batch_file"
```

OR

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
START cmd /K "path_to_new_batch_file"
```